# App don't see files

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, file

This all started when I changed my_sound.mp3 to another sound with the same name in 'Supporting Files' folder, but after compiling app was still playing the old one. After that I've done a lot of manipulations.

What I've tried:

- Delete app from iPhone and from Simulator
- Delete all from Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Product > Clean in Xcode

Now my app don't see my_sound.mp3 at all...

How I check:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) { 
    NSLog(@"No file");
}
```

Files created long time ago in 'Supporting Files' are available.

Comment: Is my_sound.mp3 listed with the correct name in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of the target's Build Phases?

Comment: Yeah. That was the problem. Huge thanks Phillip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is my_sound.mp3 listed with the correct name in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of the target's Build Phases?" – Phillip Mills Aug 4 at 19:00